# Diary Matlab :: Latest messages on top of the text file instead of append to bottom of file

Tags: matlab, logging, prepend

The **diary** function works well for logging purposes in my application, but instead of latest messages appearing on top of the text file ( this is the way I need it) it appends to older messages.

Any method to pre-append the messages rather than append to older messages in the text file or workarounds ?

Comment: Text files are written in a sequential way, inserting something at the top requires the full content to be moved. That is not supported by `diary` and even if you would find some way to hack it in, it would be very slow. Could you explain the purpose? Maybe there is a better way to achieve what you want. Could imagine a text editor which automatically scrolls so you always see the recent data would achieve what you want?

Comment: I am reading the text file generated by 'diary' on to GUI static output screen after parsing/grouping/profiling the textdata, If the log has sequential data, my GUI will show the latest messages at the bottom rather being populated at the top. Its a quick solution for application logging. Any guidance in this regard ?

Comment: Is your UI also written in m-code or some other programming language?

Comment: using matlab GUI, maybe I just try to get the displayed msgs and prepend the differences to the logGUI !

Answer (score 0):

Flipping the order should be done in the UI, here no HDD interaction is involved which will make it much faster.

At some point you need to open the logfile and initialize your data structure:

```
fid = fopen('fgetl.m');
lines = {}
```

Now read only the new lines. Repeat this cyclic:

```
tline = fgetl(fid);
new_line=false;
while ischar(tline)
    lines{end+1} = fgetl(fid);
    new_line=true
end
```

To display I recommend to display only the last n (choose a value) lines in your UI to avoid slowing down when the log grows:

```
if new_line
    reversed=lines(end:-1:max(numel(lines)-n+1,1));
    %update your UI here with the text in reversed
end
```

Finally, at the end of your program you need to close the file:

```
fclose(fid);
```